# Accessing values from pointer problem

Tags: delphi, pointers

I have a class of type TObject called CModelItem

I want to have a list of these objects and be able to modify the values of each one

So, I created a class

```
CQueueList = class(TList)

private

public

end;
```

and I make

```
QueueList : CQueueList;
```

in var

Now, I can add the CModelItem to this list, like so:

```
QueueList := CQueueList.Create;
for idx := 0 to ndx - 1 do
  begin
    MyItem := CModelItem.Create;
    MyItem.CopyHead(CModelItem(RunList.Objects[idx]));
    MyItem.ReadData;
    MyItem.NumOfIterations := NumRepEdit.Value;
    MyItem.IsInQueue := True;
    MyItem.LogEvents := EventsCheckBox.Checked;
    MyItem.LogMatch := MatchCheckBox.Checked;
    MyItem.LogUpdates := UpdatesCheckBox.Checked; 

    QueueList.Add(MyItem);
  end;
```

I can also use it, so I can do:

```
DefForm := TRunDefForm.Create(Self, QueueList.Items[idx]);
```

with DefForm taking in a component and a CModelItem

But I'm running into problems trying to modify the values of an object in QueueL

First, I can't access something like MyItem.IsInQueue by doing

```
QueueList.Items[idx].IsInQueue := blah;
```

because it tells me IsInQueue is 'an undeclared identifier'

I've also tried making a new CModelItem and copying the information over, like this:

```
idx := QueueListBox.ItemIndex;
MyItem := QueueList.Items[idx];
```

and this compiles fine, but throws up an 'access violation error' when it goes into that function

I noticed that QueueList.Items[idx] is a pointer, but I'm really not sure how I should be accessing it

Comment: According to the code you've shown, you are accessing your list correctly. Your problem lies elsewhere. What address does the AV occur at? Zero, or something else? Is it reading, or writing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler complains because `TList.Items` returns an untyped pointer.

You can use a typecast:

```
  CModelItem(QueueL.Items[idx]).IsInQueue := blah;
```

You can also reimplement the `Items` property in your `CQueueList` class:

```
private
  function GetItems(Index: Integer): CModelItem;
public
  property Items[Index: Integer]: CModelItem read GetItems; default;
end;

function CQueueList.GetItems(Index: Integer): CModelItem;
begin
  Result := inherited Items[Index];
end;
```

As you've seen, using a local variable works; although the access violation is a bug probably somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting the same access violation error doing the typecast. I'm not sure why that would happen

Comment: The access violation is probably a bug which would happen anyway. I don't see anything suspicious in the code you've posted. Maybe one of the methods `CopyHead`, `ReadData` or somewhere else.